# how to make circular dots effect in pixi js

Tags: pixi.js

I am trying to make dotted line circle using pixi.js. but don't know how to do it.
I'm trying to make some small circles and want to position them so they look like dotted lines

```js
 var dot, numDots = 80,
     radius = 168,
     circle = 1.5 * Math.PI,
     angle = circle / numDots;

 this.clock = new PIXI.Sprite();

 for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < circle; i += angle, ++j) {
     dot = new PIXI.Graphics();
     dot.beginFill(10066329, 1);
     dot.drawCircle(0, 0, 1);
     dot.angle = i - Math.PI / 2;
     if (j > 1 && j < numDots - 2) this.clock.addChildAt(dot, 0);
 }
 this.stage.addChild(this.clock);
```

Can anyone help me how to position them to form a circle?